# ViewGroup How to get child view by location (x, y)?

Tags: java, android, view, viewgroup

I am making `CustomLayout` which can contain some child views. These child views may be overlapped each other. These child view's transform matrix be modified via `setRotation` `setScale` etc.

**How we can get a child by local location (x, y)?:**

```
class CustomLayout extends ViewGroup {
    public View getChildByLocation(int x, int y) {
        // HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS
    }
}
```

*As I know so far `ViewGroup` allow us to `getChildAt(index)` so I can loop through its children to find out the view I need. But it is so complicated and I want a official way to get a child by location(x,y).*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Use this Utils class bellow. Only 1 method call needed***

*No need to subclass your layout. Call that method from main-thread, it supports translation/rotation/scale as well.*

```
// return null if no child at the position is found
View outputView = Utils.findChildByPosition(theParentViewGroup, x, y)
```

***Full Source code of class Utils:***

```
public final class Utils {
    /**
     * find child View in a ViewGroup by its position (x, y)
     *
     * @param parent the viewgourp
     * @param x      the x position in parent
     * @param y      the y position in parent
     * @return null if not found
     */
    public static View findChildByPosition(ViewGroup parent, float x, float y) {
        int count = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                if (isPositionInChildView(parent, child, x, y)) {
                    return child;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isPositionInChildView(ViewGroup parent, View child, float x, float y) {
        sPoint[0] = x + parent.getScrollX() - child.getLeft();
        sPoint[1] = y + parent.getScrollY() - child.getTop();

        Matrix childMatrix = child.getMatrix();
        if (!childMatrix.isIdentity()) {
            childMatrix.invert(sInvMatrix);
            sInvMatrix.mapPoints(sPoint);
        }

        x = sPoint[0];
        y = sPoint[1];

        return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < child.getWidth() && y < child.getHeight();
    }

    private static Matrix sInvMatrix = new Matrix();
    private static float[] sPoint = new float[2];
}
```